# Multiple mean comparison test for a Non homogeneous Poisson Process

Tags: multiple-comparisons, poisson-process, timeseries-segmentation

I do statistics for a restaurant in which people arrive at random times and end up paying a random amount of money when they are finished. I am using a Compound Poisson Process to model this, but I have an issue with fixing the rates of our guests visits: people do not arrive at the same rates for each hour, does this mean I have to asume a Non Homogeneous PP? What would be the difference betweeen this and assuming it as homogeneous, analyzing and concluding **for each different time interval**? Also, is a pairwise multiple mean comparison hypothesis test for contiguous intervals adecuate for proving a difference in rates of arrival and thus the process non homogeneity for those intervals? The operation goes for 12 hours a day.
Thanks in advance. Perhaps this is equivalent to killing a fly with a bat haha